# JetpackCompose Android - Rotate Image by an angle when clicked on it

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have scenario where I want to rotate image by an angle when clicked on it in Jetpack Compose. Please find my code below of what I tried till now:

```
@Composable
fun RotateImage() {  
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_expand_more),
        modifier = Modifier
                   .padding(end=5.dp)
                   .clickable { Modifier.rotate(angle) },
                    contentDescription = "Expandable Image"
    )
}
```

Please help me regarding this:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change angle inside Modifier.clickable instead of putting Modifier.rotate inside it.

```
@Composable
private fun RotateImage() {
    var angle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .rotate(angle)
            .clickable {
               // Change this angle as required, i set it to rotate by 90 degrees
                angle = (angle + 90) % 360f
            },
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Also, side note order of rotate and clickable determines whether clickable region also rotated. If you set rotate after clickable only content is rotated.

```
@Composable
private fun RotateImage2() {
    var angle by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable {
                angle = (angle + 90) % 360f
            }
            .rotate(angle),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

will have different outcome from the first one

Comment: As a side note would it make more sense to use `rememberSaveable { .. }` for the angle, if this is used in a `LazyColumn`, or anything that allows `RotateImage` to exit composition (screen rotation) the angle won't be "remembered".